# Hear text (screenreader) when mouse hovers over a JMenu object in Java / Windows

Tags: java, swing, accessibility

When using a screenreader, like NVDA, I want to be able to hear the text of the menu when I hover my mouse over it. I am able to hear the text when I push the buttons in the menubar, but not when I hover over them (the screenreader does reads the menu's of other programs when only hovering over the buttons).

I have set the AccessibleContext like below:

```
JMenu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("text");
JMenu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("more text");
```

I can set `listeners` to the objects that detects when a mouse hovers over them, but I do not know if/how I can cast a text to the screenreader to read. I tried `ToolTipText`, but that text is not read by the screenreader either. `RequestFocus` on the JMenu works, but setting the focus to an object just by hovering over it with the mouse provides other problems.

Does anyone knows how I can let a screenreader reads the JMenu-text when hovering with the mouse over the menubar?

I am using Java6 EE and the Java AccesBridge (version 2.02) on a Windows machine (XP and w7).

Comment: btw, if something is still unclear about the problem posted or i some crucial information is missing, feel free to tell me (as a good question is often more than the half of the answer).

Comment: Well, for starters, you are using NVDA incorrectly. NVDA is geared towards people who cannot see. So for testing, throw your mouse away, and see if you can do the following via the keyboard: press the alt key, press enter (or down key), press down key a few times, then press enter. Do you hear: {menu name}-sub-menu, {command name}? When you press enter, does that command get performed? If yes, then it is fine.

Comment: The Alt keys work and everything is read by NVDA. The problem is that in our first test, the user did not know there was a menubar, she could not 'see' it. This in contradiction to when she opened other programs where she could 'see' the menubar. With this info I started testing myself and noticed the hover-difference between our program and other programs. Therefor I asume that this difference could be the reason she does not 'see' the menubar at all. Then again, I could be wrong about how a user 'sees' the menubar. (note, our testuser uses both a screenreader and a braille keyboard)

Comment: The hover difference is not the culprit. When she was testing, did she *have* to use it, or did the script she was following (assuming there was one) guide her to do tasks that could be done via standard keboard combos? Ctrl+n, o, etc.

Comment: All the script said was to 'open a document'.

Comment: All the script said was to 'open a document'. Opening a new document goes through the menubar. Unfortunately, when she started the program she was unaware there was a menubar. This in contradiction to when she opens other programs that also have a menubar. The menubar can both be used with mouse and with keyboard. All I know, the user does not know there is a menubar in our program while she do 'sees' them in other programs. And as she was unaware of the existence of the menubar, she did not know she could use Alt(+keys) and thus had difficulties opening a document.

Comment: You could be right when saying that the hover difference is not the culprit as the problem is that the user is unaware of the menubar. I just try to figure out why and (must admit) asume it has to do with the difference in the hover effect. Should you know other methods to solve this problem, I am very much open to suggestions.

Comment: @Ryan, I hate to be picky, but I'm an NVDA user and I make regular use of its ability to read text under the mouse. So it's not entirely accurate to say that's not how you use NVDA. I'm probably what might be considered a power user though and only use that in situations where there's no choice, so I'm probably in the minority. But some people do do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is the weaker of the GUI technologies relating to accessibility in Java, compared to SWT at any rate. There's a few things you can try.

First is to make sure any accessibility fields are set (which you've started on). I can't remember if Java has an AccessibleRole field, but you can try setting that to menu and menuitem for your menu items.

Another thing you can try is the AccessibleMenu JMenu.AccessibleJMenu component. This one's the product of further reading, so I can't verify it from experience. But it and its surrounding classes may suit your needs.

If those don't work, you could try the option of talking to people's screen readers directly. Quentin C has a good library to do this, [Universal Speech](http://vrac.quentinc.net/UniversalSpeech.zip). I'm new to this library myself, but it does have a Java implementation in there that should show you how to use it in a Java program. Normally I wouldn't recommend this approach unless making the UI accessible really isn't working.

The last option would be to use the SWT components instead of the Swing ones, even if just for your menu bar. I wasn't sure how keen you'd be on this one, but it is an option and should resolve it.

I hope one of these suggestions helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have looked at the Universal Speech, but the readme-file says it only supports the Windows platform while the program I am currently writing should work on both Windows and Mac. I also tested the SWT components and they seem to work great! According to the documentation SWT should work on a Mac as well, but I have not been able to test that yet. Again, thank you for your reply!